# How to store media files in subdomain

Tags: images, redirect, media, subdomains

In order to parallelize downloads, i created already a subdomain for images. images.mydomain.com

Now, i don't know how to move my media files, without breaking attachments, and after that, in the future, how to automatically store media file in subdomain.

Eventually, what i was thinking of doing was something like , redirect images.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/wp/content/uploads and after that replace all strings 'http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/'with'http://images.mydomain.com/' using the wordpress plugin "search and replace".

Does someone believes to know how to get around this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the uploads folder to the sub domain by doing this

Open up your wp-config.php file, located at the root of your WordPress installation, and add the following code:

```
define('UPLOADS', 'http://images.mydomain.com/uploads');
```

The codex specifies that it should be added before the line that says require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);.

Make sure the uploads folder is writable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes after adding the below code also found links are broken.

`define('UPLOADS', 'http://images.mydomain.com/uploads');`

So it is also a better idea to add redirection for a 100% workable solution. [refer this](https://totalwebsecuritypro.com/how-to-move-uploads-folder-out-of-wp-content-or-to-a-subdomain-in-wordpress/)

Comment: But then every image request goes to your blog server first to be redirected to the correct place. Why not just change all of the images to the images domain without the redirect?