# Correctly using the root directory for media uploads?

Tags: uploads, media-library

I am aware what I'm attempting to do is not recommended - please don't reply just to tell me this.

I have set the uploads directory to root by adding `define( 'UPLOADS', '' );` to `wp-config.php`, which works fine except the URLs for my uploads end up with a double slash (`https://example.com//photo.jpg`). The address I've defined for my website in the General settings does not have a trailing slash.

While this doesn't break anything, it looks a little peculiar in the event anyone copies the URL, so it would be preferable to resolve. So far I've tried using an absolute URL as per [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114663/182320) (doing so just results in `https://example.com/https://example.com/photo.jpg`) and inserting a backspace character as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440110/5936778), which was a bit of a longshot.

Comment: So did you turn off the "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" setting?

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes indeed.

Comment: In that case, the answer might help you. Let me know. :)

Comment: When understanding well you have the upload folder moved directly in WP root folder? If so and just as example calling that folder storage, try adding following in `wp-config.php` code `define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'storage' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress uploads directory's path and URL are determined by the [`wp_upload_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/) function which applies a filter named `upload_dir` which you can use to fix the double slashes in the attachment URL.

So if you turned off the "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" [setting](https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-media-screen/#uploading-files), try the following:

```php
add_filter( 'upload_dir', function ( $data ) {
  $data['baseurl'] = untrailingslashit( $data['baseurl'] );
  return $data;
} );
```

And you can actually use the `upload_dir` filter to change the uploads directory path/URL/etc. without having to use the `UPLOADS` constant..

Comment: Thanks, I changed your second line to `$data['baseurl'] = '';` and it worked.